# Let $\omega$ be a primitive fifth root of unity, and let $L=\mathbb Q(\omega)$. Show $\sigma:w\mapsto w^2$ automorphism, calculate its fixed field.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $w$ be a primitive fifth root of unity, and let $L=\mathbb Q(w)$. Show that $\sigma:w\mapsto w^2$ is an automorphism of $L$ and calculate its fixed field.

I know that the minimal polynomial of $w$ is $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, but how can I show that $\sigma$ is an automorphism? Can I just say that automorphisms of $L$ permute the roots of the minimal polynomial of $w$, so then $\sigma$ is an automorphism?

Since $w\mapsto w^2$, we must have that $w^2\mapsto w^4$, $w^3\mapsto w$, and $w^4\mapsto w^3$, but I'm not sure how to use this to find which field $\sigma$ fixes. I'm not even sure of which intermediate fields there are between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q(w)$. Is there a set way to do this?

Comment: Take an element $a+bw+cw^2+dw^3$ and apply the transformation. Take into account that $w^4=-w^3-w^2-w-1$. You get $(a-c)+(d-c)w+(b-c)w^2-cw^3$. Equating coefficients you get a system of equations. You get that $b=c=d=0$.

Comment: @plop, I thought of doing something like that but I wasn't sure on what the basis elements were. I know there are four of them. Why are they those four?

Comment: Since $w^4+w^3+w^2+w+1=0$ you can always get a representative of an element of $\mathbb{Q}(w)$ to be its remainder after division by that polynomial of degree $4$. The remainders can have degree up to $3$.

Comment: Thank you! How would I say that $\sigma$ is an automorphism only given that $w\mapsto w^2$?

Comment: One way to should that it is an automorphism could be to look at the ring homomorphism $s:\mathbb{Q}[x]\to \mathbb{Q}(w)$ given by $p(x)=p(w^2)$. After doing the boring work of showing that this is a homomorphism, then you compute its kernel. Assume that $p(w^2)=0$. By dividing by the minimal polynomial of $w$ we can replace $p$ by its remainder. You do the same computation as in the first comment and equate to zero. You get that $a=b=c=d=0$. Therefore $p(x)$ must have been a multiple of $q(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. ..

Comment: Next you use the isomorphism theorems to say that $s$ induces and isomorphism  $\overline{s}:\mathbb{Q}[x]/(q(x))\to\mathbb{Q}(w)$. Finally you note that $\sigma$ is the composition $\mathbb{Q}(w)\sim\mathbb{Q}[x]/(q(x))\to\mathbb{Q}(w)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L=\mathbb Q(\omega)$

There is a unique automorphism defined by $\sigma:w\mapsto w^2$.

Any automorphism leaves the base field $\mathbb Q$ fixed, so we know $\sigma(r) = r$ when $r \in \mathbb Q$. Furthermore the equation $\sigma:w\mapsto w^2$ tells us the behavior of $\sigma$ on any power of $w$. By linearity of field automorphisms we know the unique result that any element $\sum_i c_i w^i \in L$ maps to.

---

Consider an arbitrary element $l = c_0 + c_1 w + c_2 w^2 + c_3 w^3 \in L$.

$\begin{align}
\sigma(l) =&\, c_0 + c_1 w^2 + c_2 (- 1 - w - w^2 - w^3) + c_3 w \\
=&\ (c_0 - c_2) + (c_3 - c_2) w + (c_1 - c_2) w^2 - c_2 w^3
\end{align}$.

and to have $l = \sigma(l)$ it will require $c_2 = 0$ and matching up the coefficients of $w$:

- $c_1 = c_3$
- $c_2 = c_1$
- $c_3 = -c_2$

which all together implies $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0$. So the fixed field is just $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I got something different when solving the system. For example, the element $w+w^2+w^3$ gets sent to $w^2+(-1-w-w^2-w^3)+w=-w^3-1$, not fixed.

Comment: @plop, thank you very much for catching my mistake there!